# Autocomplete for postcodes doesn't displaying data

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I am using the postcode API as a source to my autocomplete search but I cannot diplay the returned data. This API is open and the data is returned within the function but not on my html.
I might try to display the data wrong via `labelProp: $data` but anything I tried fails. 
If I change the `source: getPostcodes` of my autocomplete to some other array with data it works, but using the `getPostcodes` function it fails.
The data returned from the service for a search of '[CV5](http://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/CV5/autocomplete)' is:

```
{"status":200,"result":["CV5 6AA","CV5 6AB","CV5 6AD","CV5 6AE","CV5 6AF","CV5 6AG","CV5 6AH","CV5 6AJ","CV5 6AL","CV5 6AN"]}
```

I'm using this library for the autocomplete:
https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-jqAutocomplete

I am not sure if the 'callback' works correctly because this code is always empty:

```
<div data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(getPostcodes)"></div>
```

Any ideas??

My model:

```
  var postcode = ko.observable('');

  var getPostcodes = function(searchTerm, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            url: "http://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/" + searchTerm + "/autocomplete",
            data: { query: searchTerm },
        }).done(callback);
    }
```

My html:

```
  <input data-bind="jqAuto: { value: postcode, source: getPostcodes, labelProp: $data, valueProp: $data}" />
```

Comment: The function "getPostcodes" doesn't return anything itself so `data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(getPostcodes)"` wouldn't show anything anyways. You can test that the ajax is returning by replacing callback with your own function instead, but there's no easy way to test "callback" itself

Comment: @JasonSpake Any ideas how I would return the results?

Answer (score 1):

The results need to be formatted and stored in the callback such as:

```
}).done(function (data) {
    if (data) {
        var formatteddata = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < data.result.length; i++) {
            var item = data.result[i];
            formatteddata.push({ 'label': item, 'value': item });
        }
        callback(formatteddata);
        //return formatteddata;
    }
});
```

Comment: It's curious why that's necessary since the documentation seems to imply that if you're just returning text you can forego the 'valueProp' and 'labelProp' binding options altogether and it should just work. I'm glad you found a workaround though